# How to get sub elements of an xml in android?

Tags: android

```
InputStream is = openHTTPConnection("blahblah");
DocumentBuilderFactory fac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder;
Document doc = null;
try {
    builder = fac.newDocumentBuilder();
    doc = builder.parse(is);
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList parentNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Parent");

for (int i = 0; i < parentNodes.getLength(); i++){
   Node itemNode = parentNodes.item(i);

   if (itemNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
      Element parentElement = (Element) itemNode;

      NodeList childNodes = ??????
   }
}
```

My XML file:

```
<Blah>
   <Parent>
      <Child>
         ...
      </Child>
   </Parent>
</Blah>
```

How can I get the sub element of Parent? The tutorial says `NodeList childNodes = (parentElement).getElementsByTagName("Child");` But it does not make sense to me.

***It looks like my post is mostly code; But I don't know what to add***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tutorial is correct. This is how you get it:

```
NodeList childNodes = (parentElement).getElementsByTagName("Child");

Element childElement=(Element)childNodes.item[0];
```

In case , there are multiple `<child>` nodes, you can loop through the iterator

Comment: But it does not work, it says: The method getElementsByTagName(String) is undefined for the type Element.

Comment: Can you post the full source code, the method is present: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName(java.lang.String)

Comment: I found the error, I imported the wrong class. Now it works. Thank you very much. But the parentheses around parentElement still confuse me..

Comment: Yes, you can remove the parentheses

Answer (score 0):

In this way you can get sub elements of an xml in android

You could write a xsl

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="section">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('link ',photo@id, ' from ',@name,' is ',photo@ilink)"><xsl:value-of> 
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
run the xsl on your xml, the output will be link 1 from section1 is ImageLink 1 .. link 4 from section2 is ImageLink 2
```